# finding diagonal numbers

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

So I have this array here:

```
t = [[8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8],
     [49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0],
     [81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65],
     [52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91],
     [22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80],
     [24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50],
     [32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70],
     [67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21],
     [24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72],
     [21,36,23,9,75,0,76,44,20,45,35,14,0,61,33,97,34,31,33,95],
     [78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,3,80,4,62,16,14,9,53,56,92],
     [16,39,5,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,0,17,54,24,36,29,85,57],
     [86,56,0,48,35,71,89,7,5,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58],
     [19,80,81,68,5,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,4,89,55,40],
     [4,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,7,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66],
     [88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,3,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69],
     [4,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36],
     [20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,4,36,16],
     [20,73,35,29,78,31,90,1,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,5,54],
     [1,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,1,89,19,67,48]]
```

It's just a 2D list, what I need to do is find the four numbers diagonal to a number in any way.

I am getting the number using an xy co-ordinate and then getting the numbers around it, I thought this would be easy.

What I try to do is get the number and then find the 3 other numbers, I do this four times, for each direction

Here's the code I did to try and get it to work but it doesn't want to come out with correct numbers.

```
def getD(t,x,y):
    z = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
    xm = 1
    ym = 1
    for a in range(0,4):
        if a == 0:
            xm = 1
            ym = 1
        elif a == 1:
            xm = 1
            ym = -1
        elif a == 2:
            xm = -1
            ym = 1
        elif a == 3:
            xm = -1
            ym = -1
        for b in range(0,4):
            z[a][b]=t[y+(b*ym)][x+(b+xm)]
    print z
```

`ym` and `xm` is the direction that we want to move, so if `xm` is -1, go left, if 1 then go right, if `ym` is -1 then go down, else go up.

Anyone have any way of doing this?

If I do `getD(t, 0, 0)` then I get back `[[2, 99, 73, 4], [2, 54, 29, 72], [8, 49, 49, 95], [8, 1, 73, 36]]`

How would I emit ones that aren't valid?  For example for when it is `getD(t,0,0)` and I only want the diagonal which is down and to the right because the others cant be right?

---

Heres a formatted version of the array

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

Say I wanted all the diagonals at `(0,0)` [the top corner] using `getD(t,0,0)`

Using the code above I would want something back along the lines of:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [8, 49, 31, 23], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

or if I wanted to get diagonals at point `(19,19)` [the last bottom corner] using `getD(t, 19, 19)`

Using the code above I would want something back along the lines of:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [48, 5, 4, 40]]
```

Comment: Please include an example with the results you expect to see.  I'm having issues following what you want to get back.

Comment: Include a link to the problem you're talking about, or write it down for us.

Comment: There we go. I tried to explain, must not have said it clearly enough sorry.

Comment: i don't understand what b is for

Comment: `a` changed which list inside `z` we were changing and `b` was changing which value in the list

Comment: ASCII art such as in [`label()` function for 4-,8-connectivity might help to explain better](https://github.com/scikits-image/scikits-image/blob/master/skimage/morphology/ccomp.pyx#L79)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want something like

```
def get_diagonal(t, x, y, length=4):
    rays = []
    diagonal_directions = [(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)]
    for dx, dy in diagonal_directions:
        if not ((0 <= (x+dx*(length-1)) < len(t[0])) and
                (0 <= (y+dy*(length-1)) < len(t))):
            ray = []
        else:
            ray = [t[y+dy*i][x+dx*i] for i in range(length)]
        rays.append(ray)
    return rays
```

[Better: remove `rays` entirely and simply `yield` each ray.]

I always mix up `x` and `y` when doing this stuff, so you'll want to check that, but I think something like this should work.  Example:

```
In [48]: get_diagonal(t, 0, 0)
Out[48]: [[8, 49, 31, 23], [], [], []]

In [49]: get_diagonal(t, 19, 19)
Out[49]: [[], [], [], [48, 5, 4, 40]]

In [50]: get_diagonal(t, 5, 5)
Out[50]: [[3, 67, 20, 97], [3, 63, 42, 93], [3, 64, 68, 58], [3, 51, 23, 31]]

In [51]: get_diagonal(t, 5, 5, 3)
Out[51]: [[3, 67, 20], [3, 63, 42], [3, 64, 68], [3, 51, 23]]
```

You can change the order of `diagonal_directions` to match your expectations.  Also, note that I'm returning `[]` instead of `[0,0,0,0]` if you don't have enough terms.  Returning `[0,0,0,0]` is a bad idea, ISTM -- how would you distinguish between not having enough terms and having the right number of terms but they're all zero?  It feels weird to me to load that logic into the diagonal function, but you could easily change that.

Comment: Awesome man! I think I was on the right track but not quite there.

Comment: Now for the rest of the problem. xD. Wouldn't happen to have any code to do up, down, left and right would you? In the same format...

Comment: @SmartLemon: I'll leave that to you.  If you understand what `dx` and `dy` mean, you should be able to figure out how you can use the same approach to get those directions to work -- or how to get a knight's step to work, for that matter.

Comment: Okies. I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: Well I will when I wake up xD. Its 4.43 am in the morning at the mo so yeah xD

Answer (score 0):

Euler problem 11 is really easy with Numpy:

First, create your Numpy matrix:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> LoL=np.array([map(int,ss.split()) for ss in """\
... 08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
... 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
... 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
... 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
... 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
... 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
... 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
... 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
... 24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
... 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
... 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
... 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
... 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
... 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
... 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
... 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
... 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
... 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
... 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
... 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48\
... """.splitlines()])
```

Now, you can treat each 225 of the 4x4 matrixes as its own easy piece:

```
def maxOfSub4x4(a):
    l=[]
    for i in range(4):             # each line of 4x4 square
        l.append(a[i])
        l.append(a[:,i])

    l.append(a.diagonal())
    l.append(a[::-1].diagonal())   # opposite diagonal
    print l

    return max([reduce(int.__mul__,[int(i) for i in e]) for e in l])
```

Now the max of the particular square at LoL[0:4,0,4] can be seen:

```
    print maxOfSub4x4(LoL[0:4,0:4])
```

Prints the elements of the 4x4 sub array, including the two diagonals, and the max product of those array elements:

```
[array([ 8,  2, 22, 97]), array([ 8, 49, 81, 52]), array([49, 49, 99, 40]), array([ 2, 49, 49, 70]), array([81, 49, 31, 73]), array([22, 99, 31, 95]), array([52, 70, 95, 23]), array([97, 40, 73, 23]), array([ 8, 49, 31, 23]), array([52, 49, 99, 97])]
24468444
```

Now, just iterate over all 225 4x4 sub arrays in the 20 x 20 full array -- done.

Comment: I dont wan't to know the answer, the purpose of the project is to get people thinking.